# Fail ItemsControl binding

Tags: silverlight

I define this class :

class myClass 
{
    string Key {get;set;}
}

and the ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" >   
    <ItemsControl.Items>             
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Key}" />     
    </ItemsControl.Items> 
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, I try to call the binding in the code ( itemsControl.ItemsSource or itemsControl.DataContext  ) but its not working ( i trying to bind some list of  myClass  to the itemsControl )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the radio button inside the itemTemplate tag not the items tag

try `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate/> <DataTemplate ...`